# Django: Packages for implementing following system and newsfeed like pinterest?

Tags: python, django, pinterest, django-apps

I am currently developing an app in which I must be able to implement follow and followers system and also notifications and newsfeed.I came across various django packages,like for followers and following relations : ***django-relationships, django-follow, etc*** and for newsfeed : ***StreamFramework, django-notifier, django-notifications, etc***. So which are the best for implementing them together ? Which are the packages for getting both relations and newsfeed in my app ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For notifications, likes and feeds Stream Framework one is on its own level:

https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework

It is not Django specific, but still very easy to integrate to Django.

Comment: But it is paid, is there any free alternative?

Comment: It's open source - that's why I linked you the source code, not the paid service.

Comment: If you have little experience of running Redis, Cassandra, scalable systems, etc. then just pay them and use their service, as the challenges you face might not be trivial.

Comment: What about using pusher and django-activity-stream package together?

Comment: Will it be great to use them together, how is getstream.io better?

Comment: It is difficult to say, as there are no details of what kind of service it is, usage patterns, types of users, estimated load, development team experience, etc. Just choose what is the best for you.

Comment: If you want factual answers you please include more details in the questions. This is so wide topic that there is no one choice. There are literally hundreds of ways to do what you are asking.